# Spin up a temporary environment in Azure

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

We have a medium-sized-service architecture. What would be nice is for the programmer to be able to test his/her code in an integrated environment before merging to master.

Is there I way to start a bunch of websites in Azure based on a branch in Git? Sort of spin up a temporary environment. This environment should be teared down after the branch is merged.

I might imagine this being a gigantic topic, but for now I don't even know what to google on. If someone could point me in the right direction to get started, it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the whole infrastructure (web app) using **ARM templates** (Infrastructure as Code) inside your Release Definition. Then for each branch, you clone the environment, adjust the environment name and add an artifact filter that specifies that only artifacts from your desired branch will trigger the release. Example:

[image]

For an easy tear down, provision all necessary ressources for each branch in a separate resource group.